# X11 layer manager

Tags: c++, user-interface, x11, graphic

I have multiple applications each having a GUI from a different technology.

I need to do this -

```
 1. Create n layers, one for each application, onto which applications draw.
 2. Have a layer manager which can perform operations on each of these layers
    (like re sizing, changing opacity etc. ) and then combine them to form a 
    single layer.
```

Can someone please give an idea as to how I should proceed with this?
What APIs might help me into this ? I cant really figure out what should I be searching on google.

Language of implementation: C++

Platform : Linux

Also I would like to know if these requirements can be implemented in a platform independent way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, you want some kind of simple window manager.

If so, try to avoid using xlib, and use [QX11EmbedContainer](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qx11embedcontainer.html). Is it fairly simple to embed windows, and form layers by simply showing/hiding specific containers.

This should be a platform independent solution (should work on different hardware, but not on an non-linux OS).

---

Since you are already using QX11EmbedContainer, and have a request to use xlib only (with c++), you need to use XReparentWindowDisplay function. This is covered in the chapter 9.1 of the xlib standard (you can look it up [here](http://static.cray-cyber.org/Documentation/NEC_SX_R10_1/G1AE02E/CHAP9.HTML)). It should be pretty straight forward how to use it.

Comment: I have been using the QX11EmbedContainer only untill now. But got some specific requirement to do it in C++ only. Will it be fairly difficult to implement using XLib ?

Comment: @AmitTomar Ok, edited answer. You need to use XReparentWindowDisplay function (which is an xlib function)

Comment: Thanks. That was helpful. Just one last doubt. I can resize my container (X11 or QXEmbed). But is it possible for me to resize the application window itself after I have embedded it (Not from application side but from my window manager side)?

Comment: @AmitTomar Yes, but your application must handle resize events

Comment: But then I would have to communicate to the application to resize itself. Instead of 'telling' the application explicitly, is it possible like application's window always 'fits' the layer associated with it. By just changing the width of the layer for example, application's window automatically changes its width to fit the layer. Here I am assuming that window manager and application are separate processes.

Comment: @AmitTomar No. When the window is resized, the application will receive the resize event from the x server. Most likely (99.999%) you do not have to do anything, except for resizing the container. All gui frameworks are implementing windows resizing.