# X11 Compositor / Layer manager

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, x11, layer

I have n applications with GUIs made in different technologies.

This is what I want to do -

1. Render all application windows off-screen using a compositor (If I am using the term correctly).
2. Then combine them to form a single layer to display after applying several operations like re-sizing, changing opacity, angle etc.

Language of implementation : C++ with XLib

Can someone give me an idea how I should proceed with this ?

---

Also, I had trying doing this also and succeeded with some help from Stack Overflow-

[ [X11 layer manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10069450/x11-layer-manager) ]

1. Create n layers, one for each application, onto which applications draw.
2. Have a layer manager which can perform operations on each of these layers
   (like re sizing, changing opacity etc. ) and then combine them to form a 
   single layer.

---

Is there an advantage in terms of performance if I use the first approach ( rendering the application output myself than allowing them to do so on their own ) ? And how exactly can this be achieved.

Comment: I think you have got the wrong idea about compositor. Compositor (could be window manager (wm) or a plugin to wm like compiz) is the component which composites, i.e. it takes the offscreen buffers & creates *composited* output. What do you mean by "rendering application output *myself*"?? GUI applications make use of the underlying GUI toolkit for rendering. If you can make application render offscreen using libraries which support h/w acceleration like cairo or Qt & use your compositor to create an output (using h/w acceleration by means of OpenGL) then maybe get decent perf

Comment: @another.anon.coward So I should do this ? 1. Let applications render using their own tool-kits, off-screen. 2. Then compose these buffers to form a single layer. Can you give an idea as to how to do this ? Can I force an application to render off-screen from outside that application process ? And how is the above described way different than the one i described in [ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10069450/x11-layer-manager ]. Is off-screen rendering the step that will cause performance improvement over this method?

Comment: @another.anon.coward When I said "rendering application output myself", I meant letting the applications draw off-screen and then my compositor would combine those outputs to render one single screen, instead of letting applications render themselves on-screen and then swallowing their output inside an X11 container. I think I am still not sure which term means exactly what. And thanks for your response.

Comment: The question you have posted has response related to using Qt framework. If all you applications are using Qt for rendering then probably you can do as suggested. Unfortunately I have no clue about Qt. But it is still possible if all your application are using X server (which might be the case), you should take a look at [`xcompmgr`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xcompmgr) and its [source](http://cgit.freedesktop.org/xorg/app/xcompmgr/). That can provide you some pointers. I remember working with one such module long back, but the exact details elude me as of now :(